# The algebraic structure of a line in a (Tarski) plane

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, model-theory, foundations

By a *Tarski plane* (resp. *plane*) I understand a mathematical structure $(X,B,\equiv)$ consisting of a set $X$, a ternary betweenness relation $B\subseteq X^3$ and the 4-ary congruence relation ${\equiv}\subseteq X^2\times X^2$ satisfying the [Tarski's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) minus the Euclides parallel postulate (in which the Axiom schema of continuity is replaced by two axioms of segment-circle continuity and circle-circle continuity).

Since axioms of a Tarski plane include the axioms of a plane, each Tarski plane is a plane. In a plane one can produce standard geometric constructions with a compass and ruler.

If a plane satisfies the Euclid parallel postulate,
then it is called a *Euclidean plane*.

For distinct points $o,e\in X$ of a plane $(X,B,\equiv)$, the set $$L(o,e)=\{ x\in X:Bxoe\vee Boxe\vee Boex \}$$is called the *line* containing the points $o,e$.

The line $L(o,e)$ carries a unique structure of a linearly ordered commutative group $(L(o,e),+,\le)$ such that

$\bullet$ $o$ is zero of $L(o,e)$ and $o<e$,

$\bullet$ for any $x,y\in L(o,e)$ we have $x\le y$ iff $Bxyo\vee 
 Bxoy\vee Boxy$,

$\bullet$ for any $x,y,z\in L(o,e)$ with $o\le x$ and $o\le y$ we have $z=x+y$ if and only if $Boxz$ and $xz\equiv oy$.

If the plane is Euclidean (and Tarski), then the line $L(o,e)$ carries a structure of a (real closed) ordered field such that $e$ is the unit of $L(o,e)$ and for any element $y\in L(o,e)$ with $o\le y$ there exists $x\in L(o,e)$ such that $x^2=y$.

> **Question.** What is an algeraic structure of a line $L(o,e)$ in a (Tarski) plane? It should be something more general than the structure of a (real-closed) ordered field, closed under taking square roots.

Or more precisely:

> **Problem.** *Characterize ordered groups, which are isomorphic to the lines in (Tarski) planes*.

Comment: I do not fathom the downvotes on this interesting question.

Comment: Looking at the question from non-semantic POV, I doubt the premise that "curvature" should somehow affect algebraic structure of lines; geodesics in hyperbolic plane (or, fwiw, any reasonable Alexandrov plane-like space) are usual lines, curvature only comes into play when you consider triangles. That structure can be possibly encoded algebraically as an operation on set of  *lines*, which are otherwise more or less indistinguishable.

Comment: @DenisT I had in mind that the line in an non-Euclidean absolute plane should be closed under certain (probably, hyperbolic) functions (corresponding to constructions with compass and ruler), which include some parameters which can be interpreted as the curvature of the absolute plane. A line in an elementary absolute plane can be countable, in fact, a minimal model of an elementary absolute plane is countable. Observe that instead of a full continuity axiom we have two axioms postulating the existence of points in the intersections of circles and lines.

Comment: Aren’t these simply the euclidean fields? Can’t you construct a hyperbolic plane over any such field? (You can certainly construct a euclidean plane.) My memory may be rusty, but I believe such questions are answered in the Schwabhäuser–Szmielew–Tarski monograph.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Indeed, lines in Euclidean planes are isomorphic to Euclidean fields. But in hyperbolic planes this is not true anymore because the ratio (the longest length)/(side) in a right isosceles triangle in the hyperbolic plane does not belong to the smallest Euclidean field (I hope so). For a hyperbolic plane the lines should carry a structure of an ordered field, closed under some functions of many variables (corresponding to constructions with compass and ruler). So, my question is to determine those functions and the smallest number of such functions.

Comment: I looked it up. By I.16.15, planes (Tarski planes) satisfying the Euclidean parallel postulate are exactly the Cartesian planes over Euclidean (real-closed, resp.) fields. By II.2.5, planes (Tarski planes) satisfying the hyperbolic parallel postulate are exactly the Kleinian planes over Euclidean (real-closed, resp.) fields. By point (vi) in §II.2.3, every Tarski plane satisfies one of the two parallel postulates; I’m not sure if this holds only assuming the circle axiom, but the table in §II.2.16 seems to suggest so.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek In particular, the lines in a plane should be closed under the function $f:L\times L\to L$ assigning to any $a,b\in L$ the longest length of a right triangle with sides of length $|a|$ and $|b|$. In Euclidean plane, $f(a,b)=\sqrt{s^2+b^2}$ by the Pitagoras Theorem, but in the hyperbolic plane, $f(a,b)$ is more complicated: $cosh(f(a,b))=cosh(a)cos(b)$, see https://web.colby.edu/thegeometricviewpoint/2014/03/28/pythagoras-in-the-hyperbolic-plane/

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you for the reference (to Schwabhäuser–Szmielew–Tarski). Unfortunately, I do not read German (at least fluently), but somehow it seems to me that for a subfield of $\mathbb R$ to be closed under the function $cosh^{-1}(cosh(a)\cosh(b))$ does not follow from the real closedness, so I do not believe that Tarski hyperbolic planes are Kleinian planes over real closed fields (in some of such planes the axiom of Segment Construction will not hold). But maybe I am wrong, not being an expert in this field.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I looked at II.2.4 and found there a formula for calculating distances in the Kleinian model, witnessing that indeed, every line in the (Tarski) hyperbolic plane should be algebraically closed (resp. Euclidean). Very-very strange for me! Could you write down this your comment as an answer and I will accept it to close this question? Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that your link uses a different measure of length than what’s implied in the Klein models of Tarski geometry? The reason I only posted it as a comment is that I'm still not sure whether Euclidean and hyperbolic planes exhaust all planes in absence of the full schema of continuity.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek All such formulas for length should be isomorphic in some sense. Now I simply admit that $cosh^{-1}(cosh(a)cosh(b))$ is algebraically dependent on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  Concerning your second sentence, I also am hesitating because the structure of a line $L(o,e)$ in a non-Euclidean plane can essentially depend on the choice of the points $o,e$. In this case there is a minimal countable submodel containing $o,e$ and it is not evident at all why it should contain the absolute unit of length, equal to the length of the side of a regular ideal triangle with one ideal vertex and one angle equal to $\pi/4$. So, for some $e$ the line $L(o,e)$ does contain this absolute unit of length and for another does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is addressed by W. Schwabhäuser on p. 156 of his paper *Metamathematical methods in foundations of geometry*. Logic, Methodology and Philosophy of Science (Proc. 1964 Internat. Congr.) North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1965, pp. 152–165. If the Tarski plane (as you have defined it) is hyperbolic (i.e. not Euclidean), then by a result of W. Szmielew (*A new analytic approach to hyperbolic geometry*. Fund. Math. 50 (1961/62), pp. 129–158) the plane is isomorphic to a Klein space over a Euclidean ordered field if and only if the plane satisfies Hilbert's hyperbolic axiom of parallels. If it does not satisfy Hilbert's axiom then the algebraic characterization is substantially more complicated and can be obtained from Pejas's classification of Hilbert planes, as discussed in W. Pejas, *Die Modelle des Hilbertschen Axiomensystems der absoluten Geometrie*, Math. Ann. 143 (1961), 212–235 and in F. Bachmann *Zur Parallelenfrage* Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg 27 (1964), 173–192. Unfortunately, I no longer have these papers and it's been so long since I've studied the matter, I can't be of help with the details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the references.

Comment: So, at least for the Klein plane $K$ over a Euclidean field $E$ each line in $K$ is isomorphic (as an ordered group) to the additive group $\ln[E]:=\{t\in \mathbb R:e^t\in E\}$? And this is a desirable characterization of the lines in hyperbolic Tarski planes that satify the Hilbert hyperbolic axiom. Right?

Comment: Are you assuming K satisfies the Archimedean axiom? Your definition of ln[E] seems to suggest this.

Comment: Yes, for defining $\ln[E]$ in the real line I indeed need the Archimedean axiom. In the non-Archimedean case we can consider the Lobachevskyi function $L(\alpha)$ assigning to each acute angle $\alpha$ in the length of the unique bounded side a right idean triangle with an an angle $\alpha$ and two infinite sides. According to Bonola's consruction such a triangle can be constructed using the ruler and compass. Then each line in $K$ is isometrically isomorphic to the ordered group $\{L(\alpha):\cos(\alpha)\in E\}$, where we identify angles in $K$ with suitable angles in the completion of $E^2$.

Comment: OK, yes, for the Archimedean case, that seems right. By the way, if I remember correctly, by a result of M. J. Greenberg (On J. Bolyai's parallel construction. J. Geom. 12 (1979), no. 1, pp. 45–64), Archimedean, non-Euclidean Tarski planes always satisfy Hilbert's hyperbolic parallel axiom.